# using Generic interface type as basis for interface parameter type

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following:

```
class Item {
  public object ItemId {get;set;}
}

class StringItem : Item {
  public new string ItemId {get;set;}
}

interface IItemRepository<out T> : where T : Item {
  T GetItem(object itemId);
}
```

What I'd like is to be able to replace object itemId with the type of ItemId based on what implementation I'm using.  I can do it using IItemRepository where U is the ItemId type, but I'd like to tie the itemId type directly to the ItemId Property Type.  Also, I'm not necessarily tied to using IItemRepository as an interface.  I could make it an abstract class, but I didn't see an easy way to do it that way either.

so, the end result is that I could do:

```
StringItemRepository : IItemRepository<StringItem> {
  StringItem GetItem(string itemId) { ... }
}
```

and that would satisfy the Interface.  Is there a way to do something like :

```
T GetItem(typeof(T.ItemId.GetType()) itemId);
```

Update:
I cannot simply do  IItemRepository , as I'll have multiple implementations of Item.  each implementation will also have a repository (possibly multiple).  so, the final WebService will have something like:

```
IEnumerable<IItemRepository<Item>> Repositories;
```

This list of repositories will be used to generate all different types of Items.  I need to be able to distinguish between a Foo : Item and a Bar : Item ... I may just have to pass along the ItemIdType to the Repository, but it just feels clunky.  Seems like I'm repeating myself and there should be some way to refactor this so I dont have to.

Another Update... So... Here's what I've started to come up with:

```
class Item<T> { 
  public T id {get;set;}
}

class StringItem : Item<string> {
  public string id {get;set;}
}

interface IItemRepo<T> {
  Item<T> GetItem(T id);
}

class StringItemRepository : IItemRepo<string> {
  public StringItem GetItem(string id) { return null}
}
```

The issue is that I need the StringItemRepository.GetItem to spit out StringItems, not Item objects.  and my current implementation doesn't work cause StringItemRepository isn't implementing GetItem cause it's not returning Item ... You'd think that since StringItem is a Item it'd work, but no such luck.

I think I'm going to have to use 2 generic types.. (both the StringType and String) when I create the Repository unless someone else has another solution..

Okay... So, this worked:

```
class Item<T> { 
  public T id {get;set;}
}

class StringItem : Item<string> {
  public string id {get;set;}
}

interface IItemRepo<T> {
  Item<T> GetItem(T itemId);
}

class StringItemRepository : IItemRepo<string> {
  public Item<string> GetItem(string itemId) { 
    return new StringItem(); 
  }
}
```

I was hung up on having GetItem having a stringItem as a return type, but I can return a StringItem since it  of type Item ... This will work out perfectly... thanks for all that helped out..

Comment: Why not make an Item<T> generic type which inherits from Item and overrides the ItemId to handle type casting?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Just what I was suggesting - although unless you really need the non-generic type, I'd get rid of that too :)

Comment: @JonSkeet For shizzle, just thought maybe ItemId was untyped for a reason like some other managing class not knowing/caring about types.  Also EEEEEEEEEEEE first reply from Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should make `Item` generic to start with - then you don't need `StringItem` at all, with its property hiding:

```
class Item<T> {
  public T ItemId { get; set; }
}

interface IItemRepository<T> {
  Item<T> GetItem(T itemId);
}
```

Comment: Just needs the `T` in the property: `public T ItemId { get; set; }`

Comment: Yeah, duh.  I guess if i'm going to use generics, may as well USE them.. (:  sometimes it's the easy things that get glazed over.  Thanks man.

Comment: @Rob I have the same problem playing Portal.  I frequently forget that I have an Aperture Science Handheld Portal Device making my life so much more difficult.

Comment: Hmmm.. This may not work afterall.. I'm close though.. I'll post the final answer after.  See, I want to instantiate the repository like so : StringItemRepository : IItemRepository <StringItem> because I'm using StringItem in other method calls as well... but.. I think I get the jist here..

Comment: @Rob: Do you *need* to use `StringItem` rather than `Item<String>`? Does `StringItem` have something *else* important about it?

Comment: nope.. it worked how you said it would.  I had another method Signature IEnumerable<T> GetMeetingItems(whatever)... so, I changed it to IEnumerable<Item<T>> GetMeetingItems(whatever)... it seems to work, so, I'm going to go with it.  I know either StyleCop or FxCop yells at nested generics, but too bad in this case.. any other refactoring will most likely make is less readable

Comment: okay.. yes.  StringItem does have a significance.  I may have two items that both implement Item<string>.  I'll update my question.

Comment: @Rob: If you have two items that both implement `Item<string>`, that's fine - it doesn't mean that it's a good idea to have a separate `StringItem` class, IMO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11384/discussion-between-rob-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 0):

Why not implementing this like;

```
public class Item<T>
{
    public T ItemId { get; set; }
}

public class StringItem<T> : Item<T>
{

}

public interface IItemRepository<T>
{
    Item<T> GetItem(T itemId);
}

public class StringItemRepository<T> : IItemRepository<T>
{
    public Item<T> GetItem(T itemId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: `StringItem` would probably look like this: `public class StringItem : Item<String>`

Comment: @SwDevMan81 you may be right, in fact if something custom is not implemented, it can be removed also. But if the class has any other method which needs to employ T, it may be preserved. Lots of maybes.

Comment: Indeed... stringItem is indeed Item<string> and therein lies the problem.. (: